# Access Denied <Directory name> in Visual studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am starting to learn c# and when I click New project>C#>Console Application in VS 2013, I get the error message telling me the access is denied to C:/.
I ran as admin but no use. What is the problem?

Comment: Try to save the project at default VS project location instead of c:\ and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this thing:

1. Run visual studio as administrator or
2. Open visual studio. **Tools** **Menu** | **Options** | **Projects and Solutions** | Check the checkbox "**Save new projects when created**".
3. Change projects location in same dialog. Change it to some other directories like D:\Projects.

Hope this will resolve your issue.